# Unknown "white rectangle" system notification icon on Samsung Galaxy

Tags: notification-icons

I have Samsung Galaxy S7 running on Android 7.0 Nougat. I got a new notification symbol that looks like a white rectangle on the right side (which is usually for system icons).

[image: "white rectangle" icon on the right side/system icon]

Sometimes it's gone while I'm browsing with the Chrome browser but then it's back.

I don't use or install any Cast apps. Long-pressing the icon only open the notification bar, but no additional information. Toggling GPS, NFC, Bluetooth didn't help.

What does this icon represent?

Answer (score -1):

Pull down the notification bar and long press on that notification, you should see the app associated with this icon. This could belong to an app you installed.

Comment: This method disappeared after Lollipop I suppose.

Comment: Nope, it still exists! Simply touch the i symbole

Comment: It's on the right, meaning it is a system icon. It isn't a notification you can long press.